# Динамически изменяющийся заголовок пункта меню

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, binding

Имеется `UserControl` `Sector`, у него есть свойство `IsSectorEnabled`.
Необходимо добавить к нему контекстное меню, в котором заголовок пункта меню (`MenuItem Header`) меняется в зависимости от свойства `IsSectorEnabled`.
Сделать `binding` через `DataTrigger` не получается:

```
<UserControl x:Class="UserControlLibrary.SectorGrid"
             xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
             xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
             xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
             xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008" 
             xmlns:local="clr-namespace:UserControlLibrary"
             mc:Ignorable="d"
             d:DesignHeight="300" d:DesignWidth="300">

    <UserControl.Resources>
        <Style x:Key="MenuItemStyle" TargetType="{x:Type MenuItem}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:Sector}}, Path=IsSectorEnabled}" Value="True">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="Disable"/>
                </DataTrigger>
                <DataTrigger Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Mode=FindAncestor, AncestorType={x:Type local:Sector}}, Path=IsSectorEnabled}" Value="False">
                    <Setter Property="Header" Value="Enable"/>
                </DataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>

        <Style x:Key="SectorStyle" TargetType="{x:Type local:Sector}">
            <Setter Property="ContextMenu">
                <Setter.Value>
                    <ContextMenu>
                        <MenuItem Style="{StaticResource MenuItemStyle}"/>
                    </ContextMenu>
                </Setter.Value>
            </Setter>
        </Style>
    </UserControl.Resources>

    <UniformGrid Name="uGrid" Columns="5" Rows="5">
        <local:Sector Id="1" Text="A1" Style="{StaticResource SectorStyle}"/>
        <local:Sector Id="2" Text="A1" Style="{StaticResource SectorStyle}"/>
        <local:Sector Id="3" Text="A1" Style="{StaticResource SectorStyle}"/>
        <local:Sector Id="4" Text="A1" Style="{StaticResource SectorStyle}"/>
        <local:Sector Id="5" Text="A1" Style="{StaticResource SectorStyle}"/>
        <local:Sector Id="6" Text="A1" Style="{StaticResource SectorStyle}"/>
        <local:Sector Id="7" Text="A1" Style="{StaticResource SectorStyle}"/>
        <local:Sector Id="8" Text="A1" Style="{StaticResource SectorStyle}"/>
        <local:Sector Id="9" Text="A1" Style="{StaticResource SectorStyle}"/>
        <local:Sector Id="10" Text="A1" Style="{StaticResource SectorStyle}"/>
        <local:Sector Id="11" Text="A1" Style="{StaticResource SectorStyle}"/>
        <local:Sector Id="12" Text="A1" Style="{StaticResource SectorStyle}"/>
        <local:Sector Id="13" Text="A1" Style="{StaticResource SectorStyle}"/>
        <local:Sector Id="14" Text="A1" Style="{StaticResource SectorStyle}"/>
        <local:Sector Id="15" Text="A1" Style="{StaticResource SectorStyle}"/>
        <local:Sector Id="16" Text="A1" Style="{StaticResource SectorStyle}"/>
        <local:Sector Id="17" Text="A1" Style="{StaticResource SectorStyle}"/>
        <local:Sector Id="18" Text="A1" Style="{StaticResource SectorStyle}"/>
        <local:Sector Id="19" Text="A1" Style="{StaticResource SectorStyle}"/>
        <local:Sector Id="20" Text="A1" Style="{StaticResource SectorStyle}"/>
        <local:Sector Id="21" Text="A1" Style="{StaticResource SectorStyle}"/>
        <local:Sector Id="22" Text="A1" Style="{StaticResource SectorStyle}"/>
        <local:Sector Id="23" Text="A1" Style="{StaticResource SectorStyle}"/>
        <local:Sector Id="24" Text="A1" Style="{StaticResource SectorStyle}"/>
        <local:Sector Id="25" Text="A1" Style="{StaticResource SectorStyle}"/>
    </UniformGrid>
</UserControl>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Проблема вот в чём. Вы пытаетесь «достучаться» из `MenuItem`'а до элемента, на котором был произведён клик, поиском вверх по дереву элементов. Это не работает вот по какой причине.

При открытии контекстного меню возникает `Popup`, который является отдельным корневым элементом в дереве. Таким образом, идя от `MenuItem`'а, вы попадаете в `ContextMenu`, затем в `Popup`, и на этом всё.

Но выход есть: `ContextMenu` имеет свойство `PlacementTarget`, которое хранит тот элемент в основном дереве, на котором был произведён клик!

Таким образом, ваш код должен быть следующим:

```
<DataTrigger
    Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource FindAncestor, AncestorType=ContextMenu},
                      Path=PlacementTarget.IsSectorEnabled}"
    Value="True">
    <Setter Property="Header" Value="Disable"/>
</DataTrigger>
```

Comment: Огромное спасибо за развернутый, исчерпывающий ответ!

Comment: @Zer0CooL: Пожалуйста!