# WPF ContextMenu

Tags: c#, wpf

Пытаюсь перенести команду удаления строки в *ContextMenu* при выполнения команды выходит ошибка

> SelectedItem  MenuItem.CommandParameter   Object  Не удается найти
> источник: ElementName=dtgd1.

Подскажите как решить данную проблему.

```
<DataGrid.ContextMenu>
    <ContextMenu>
        <MenuItem Header="Delete" Command="{Binding DeleteCommand}"
                  CommandParameter="{ Binding ElementName=dtgd1,  Path=SelectedItem}"/>
    </ContextMenu>
</DataGrid.ContextMenu>
```

Comment: попробуй не через `ElementName` прибиндить, а создать отдельное свойство и биндиться уже к нему

Comment: Привязка контекстного меню делается через `PlacementTarget` [1](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/656197/373567), [2](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/431100/373567)